# Rails : redirect on page if user profile not filled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, process, registration, profile

I'm actually building a system where users, after registering on my application and confirm their account by email, will be redirected to a wizard process page (build in Js) where they will be asked to fill in some more information.

To do that, I create a function in my app controller which will redirect the user to that process page, according to certain condition :

```
// application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :fill_in_profile

  protected
    def fill_in_profile
      if user_signed_in?
        if current_user.employee? && !current_user.filled?
          redirect_to new_profile_path
        end
      end
    end
end
```

The problem here is that Im getting a 302 status error because it's creating an infinite redirection loop.
So I wanted to know how you guys were handling those kind of page and process?

Thanks

Comment: What is `.filled?` method?

Comment: Please post the user controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `skip_before_action` in your `ProfilesController` (or wherever `new_profile_path` points to):

```
class ProfilesController
  skip_before_action :fill_in_profile

  def new
    # …
  end
end
```

I'd love to recommend a link into the Rails API, but neither [`AbstractController::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks.html) nor [`AbstractController::Callbacks::ClassMethods.skip_before_filter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-skip_before_action) looks promising…